# Html table displaying date time instead of date

Tags: c#, html

I am getting a table from database and creating it as an html table to send automated mail..the table has date modified section and another column which has only date and not t..but while it is getting converted to html table the date column shows date along with time.
My html table structure:
Other dynamic function:

```
public string GetHtmlTable(string title, DataTable table)
        {
            try
            {
                string messageBody = "<font> "+title+" </font><br><br>";

                if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
                    return messageBody;
                string htmlTableStart = "<table style=\"border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;\" >";
                string htmlTableEnd = "</table>";
                string htmlHeaderRowStart = "<tr style =\"background-color:#6FA1D2; color:#ffffff;\">";
                string htmlHeaderRowEnd = "</tr>";
                string htmlTrStart = "<tr style =\"color:#555555;\">";
                string htmlTrEnd = "</tr>";
                string htmlTdStart = "<td style=\" border-color:#5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding: 5px;\">";
                string htmlTdEnd = "</td>";

                messageBody += htmlTableStart;

                messageBody += htmlHeaderRowStart;
                
                foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    messageBody += htmlTdStart + column + htmlTdEnd;

                messageBody += htmlHeaderRowEnd;

                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    messageBody +=  htmlTrStart;


                    foreach (string item in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        messageBody += htmlTdStart;
                        messageBody += item;
                        messageBody += htmlTdEnd;
                    }
                    messageBody += htmlTrEnd;
                }
                messageBody += htmlTableEnd;


                return messageBody;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I'm sending the table genereated to this html query and generating it as html string and i'l mail it as message body..my requirement is I need to get date and not time...i don't have time in my SQL column from where I get the table.plz help.
[What i get in date modified and other date column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iyzi.jpg)
I need only date and not time

Comment: Format the date as a string when you pull it into the DataTable, or truncate the time when it's pulled from the Database.

Comment: I tried ..the thing is in SQL table there is only date no time...but how I'm getting time

Comment: the time is implicitly created when the date loads from the database into the DataTable as a DateTime object.

You need to format the date as a string with the date format mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` has a `ToString()` function that allows you to pass in formatting, such as "yyyy-MM-dd" . . . for example:

`var dateOnly = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

There is also a `DateOnly` type, as in:

`DateOnly dateOnly = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I pass the whole table into the html section i don't have time in the SQL data..even though I tried formating the date as date while reading the table

Comment: @dona The .Net `DateOnly` type is fairly new, and was not available when ADO.Net was created. Therefore a SQL Server `Date` column still maps to a C# `datetime` value, which of course **does** have a time value. It's just the time portion will always be midnight. The `item` variable in the code will itself have a type of `object`, but the type of each actual value in the variable will be determined by this ADO.Net mapping. Your code will need to be smart enough to detect this and use the appropriate format string.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn so is there any way..i m new to this

Comment: @dona It means you don't get to assume every value is already in the correct string format. Your code has to know more about what you want each part of the html table to look like. You'll have to write the details for this yourself. There's nothing that will do that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant part of the code is here:

```
foreach (string item in row.ItemArray)
{
    messageBody += htmlTdStart;
    messageBody += item;
    messageBody += htmlTdEnd;
}
```

The type of the `row.ItemArray` property is `object?[]`. Therefore the core type of the `item` variable in the loop is `object?`. This means the `messageBody += item;` line is relying on an implicit call to the `.ToString()` method.

Furthermore, the **actual type** of the value in the `item` variable on each iteration is determined by the ADO.Net mapping from the original database type to C#.

We know the type of the database column is `date`, because there is no time portion in the database. So what ADO.Net *should* do is map the column to a C# `DateOnly` value. Unfortunately, `DateOnly` is relatively new; it wasn't available until more than 15 years after ADO.Net was written. Therefore ADO.Net instead will map the value to a C# `DateTime` value. And `DateTime` values **always** have a time component; it's just the time component will be set at all 0s (midnight) for the date retrieved from the database.

So now we know enough to understand what is happening: we have a implicit call to `DateTime.ToString()` for the value, and therefore you see a time when you don't want to. You'll find you have a similar problem for `double` and `decimal` values.

The result is you need to make this loop smarter. A **LOT** smarter. In fact, you'll probably find it's not feasible to use a generic `DataTableToHTML()` function at all, because **in practice nearly every single HTML table you create needs special formatting for at least one column.** Sometimes you'll want to treat `NULL` in different ways. Sometimes you'll want specific currency formatting for a decimal, sometimes not. Sometimes you'll want to truncate the time portion off a DateTime value, even if there really is a time portion present.

So instead I would tend to write a method to require a lambda argument for the row formatting, like this:

```
public string GetHtmlTable(string title, DataTable table, Func<string, DataRow> formatRowCells)
{
    var tableResult = new StringBuilder($"<div class=\"generatedTableTitle\">{title}</div>");

    if (table.Rows.Count == 0) return tableResult.ToString();

    string htmlTableStart = "<table class=\"generatedTable\">";
    string htmlTableEnd = "</table>";
    string htmlHeaderRowStart = "<tr class=\"generatedHeaderRow\">";
    string htmlHeaderRowEnd = "</tr>";
    string htmlThStart = "<th>";
    string htmlThEnd = "</th>";
    string htmlTrStart = "<tr>";
    string htmlTrEnd = "</tr>";

    tableResult.AppendLine(htmlTableStart)
               .AppendLine(htmlHeaderRowStart);

    foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        tableResult.Append($"{htmlTrStart}{column}{htmlThEnd}");

    tableResult.AppendLine(htmlHeaderRowEnd);

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        tableResult.AppendLine(htmlTrStart)
                   .AppendLine(formatRowCells(row))
                   .AppendLine(htmlTrEnd);
    }

    tableResult.AppendLine(htmlTableEnd);
    return tableResult.ToString();
}
```

Then I would still support the original as a method overload I could use for the most basic tables that really don't need any special formatting, like this:

```
public string GetHtmlTable(string title, DataTable table)
{
    return GetHtmlTable(title, table, row => string.Join("", row.ItemArray.Select(td => $"<td>{td}</td>")));       
}
```

But for your specific case I would instead call the method like this:

```
string MyTable = GetHtmlTable(title, table, row =>
    {
        var rowResult = new StringBuilder();

        int dateColumnIndex = 2; // put the date column index here
        for (int c = 0; c < row.ItemArray.Length; c++)
        {
            string cellValue = row[c];
            if (c == dateColumnIndex)
               cellValue = row[c].ToString("d");
            rowResult.Append($"<td>{cellValue}</td>");
        }
        return rowResult.ToString();
    });
```

Or for fun we can use the new `switch` pattern matching:

```
string MyTable = GetHtmlTable(title, table, row =>
    {
        var rowResult = new StringBuilder();

        int dateColumnIndex = 2; // put the date column index here
        for (int c = 0; c < row.ItemArray.Length; c++)
        {
            string cellValue = switch c
            {
                dateColumnIndex => row[c].ToString("d"),
                _ => row[c]
            };
            rowResult.Append($"<td>{cellValue}</td>");
        }
        return rowResult.ToString();
    });
```

This is actually slightly longer, but it makes it easier to target a number of different columns in a readable way if a row is more complex.

Finally, note how I removed most of the styling. That's because I added the `generatedTable` css class at the beginning of the element. Now we can put styles to target these tables (and *only* these tables) in the main css like this:

```
<style>
    div.generatedTableTitle {margin-bottom:2em;font-family:missing_from_question;}
    table.generatedTable {border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;}
    table.generatedTable tr { color:#555555; }
    table.generatedTable td { border-color:#5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding: 5px; }
    table.generatedTable tr.generatedHeaderRow {background-color:#6FA1D2; color:#ffffff;}
    table.generatedTable th { border-color:#5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding: 5px; }
</style>
```

This will significantly reduce the download size of your pages, making them seem faster, making it easier to tweak the visual layout of the tables, and making the table code more re-usable.